# How can I find a line according with two subsequent words in a text file

Tags: python, search, text, cpu-word

I am very new to Python so please excuse ignorant questions or overly complicated code. :)
I am very thankful for any help.

The code I have so far is to open read a/several text files, search the lines according to keywords
and then write a new textfiles while leaving out the lines with found keywords. This is to clean the files (newspaper articles) of information I do not want to have before analysing the remaining text. The problem is that I am only able to search for single words. However, sometimes I would like to search for a specific combination of words, i.e. not just "Rechte", but "Alle Rechte vorbehalten".
If I save this into my delword-list, it doesn't work (I think because part in line.split only checks single words.)

Any help is very much appreciated!

```py
    import os
    
    delword = ['Quelle:', 'Ressort:', 'Ausgabe:', 'Dokumentnummer:', 'Rechte', 'Alle Rechte vorbehalten']
    
    path = r'C:\files'
    pathnew = r'C:\files\new'
    
    dir = []
    
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith(".txt"):
            #print(os.path.join(path, f))
            print(f)
            if f not in dir:
                dir.append(f)
             
    for f in dir:
        
        fpath = os.path.join(path, f)
        print (fpath)
        fopen = open(fpath, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
        printline = True
        #print(fopen.read())
        fnew = 'clean' + f
        fpathnew = os.path.join(pathnew, fnew)
    
        with open(fpath, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as input:
            with open(fpathnew, "w", errors='ignore') as output: 
                for line in input:
                    printline = True
                    for part in line.split():
                        for i in range(len(delword)):
                                if delword [i] in part:
                                    #line = " ".join((line).split())
                                    printline = False
                                    #print('Found: ', line)
                    if printline == False:
                        output.write('\n')
                    if printline == True:
                        output.write(line)
                    
        
        input.close()
        output.close()
        fopen.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case - you don't need to split the line. You can run similar checks with

```
for line in input:
    for word in delword:
        if word in line: ...
```

Just as side note: usually more generic or complex problems will be using regular expressions, as tool created for such processing